# Swift Message Parser : Equivalent of prowide core in C#

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, swift-mt

Is there, in 2021, an existing lib for c# that allows us to parse any type of swift message like it seems to be the case in java with the prowide core lib (WIFE) ?

I would really appreciate that but can't find anything, any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm part of Prowide.

We do have a port to NET framework, for the MT features (not for the ISO 20022 library). Would that do? I'm not aware of any native C# similar library.

Comment: Could you please point me towards this .NET port? I haven't been able to find any other mention of it.

Comment: Yes, please can use the online form at
https://www.prowidesoftware.com/contact-us
Then someone will reach you out with the information of the ported library